# Per Machine Application Data Folder

Tags: c#, .net, special-folders, app-certification-kit

I am using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

to get the path to store user data. That equates to:

```
C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming
```

If I go through the Windows 8.1 desktop application certification on a per user, then I receive no warnings. If I select, "Per Machine", then I receive the following warning:

```
Multiuser session test
WARNING 
Do not write to the 'Users' folder
Warning: The user folder test detected the following errors: 
File C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\<MyCompany>\<MyApp>\<MyFile> was written to an incorrect location.


Impact if not fixed: Different users might not be able to run the app in concurrent sessions. 

How to fix:  The app must run in multiple concurrent local and remote sessions. The app should not require administrator privileges when it runs. User data and settings must be isolated to the user’s profile. See link below for more information: 
Remote Desktop Services programming guidelines
```

1. What is wrong with writing to the folder for multiple users?
2. What folder / constant do I use to write for multiple users, if not that?

I realize that I can write to the MyDocuments folder, however that is not the right location. I like the benefits. Besides, if two different users would log onto the system, then:

```
C:\Users\<User1>\AppData\Roaming
C:\Users\<User2>\AppData\Roaming
```